# RichTextBox - UI Resize causes huge CPU Load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've recently been developing an RTF Editor which is only a simple `UserControl` that has a `RichTextBox` with a couple Events like `PreviewTextInput` and `PreviewMouseUp`.

I noticed something slightly annoying though.
The Performance of the `RichTextBox` is absolutely terrible whenever the UI is being resized and the `RichTextBox` has a lot of Text to cause its Wrapping Algorithm to fire.

This gives the Application a really sloppy feel, as if it is poorly optimized (even though it isn't).

At first I noticed this performance hit while selecting Text, so instead of using the `SelectionChanged` event, I decided to use the `PreviewMouseUp` event and then fetch the Selection.

Then after further testing I found out that the resize also caused huge loads.
And I'm talking about loads ranging between 5% -> 30% with a Quad-Core CPU running at 3.8GHz!

To further test it out, I decided to comment out my `RichTextBox` and only include a new `RichTextBox` with no defined Property

```
<RichTextBox/>
```

Inserting this into a Window, filling with Text, and then resizing the Window to cause the Wrapping Algorithm did the same again, up to 30% usage!

I tried to research about this matter, and most people ended up recommending setting the `PageWidth` to high values in order to prevent Wrapping:

```
richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
richTextBox1.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
```

Which I do not want, since the previous Version of the Editor I wrote was made with WinForms and could do Wrapping effortlessly, and I also want it in the new WPF Version.

Did anyone else ever face this issue?
If yes, could you please point me into the right direction to remove this huge strain on the hardware?

I'm a bit sad because I love WPF, but I did find one or the other Object that is really unoptimized and/or not practical in comparison to the WinForms counterpart, the `RichTextBox` seems to be another one of those cases :(

Sorry for the huge amount of Text, but I really wanted to Document this neatly in case some other poor soul faces this issue and for you guys to see what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to overcome this issue might be to switch to "no wrap" mode when window is being resized, but when user finished with resizing - switch back to normal mode. Then wrapping algorithm will be executed just once at the end and users should still have smooth feeling about your application. Sample code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private Timer _timer;
    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        // user started resizing - set large page width
        textBox.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
        // if we already setup timer - stop it and start all over
        if (_timer != null) {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }

        _timer = new Timer(_ => {
            // this code will run 100ms after user _stopped_ resizing
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                // reset page width back to allow wrapping algorithm to execute
                textBox.Document.PageWidth = double.NaN;
            });
        }, null, 100, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny how I didn't think about the obvious choice which is fetching the Resize Call, I guess I'm too tired. There is an error in your code where you're trying to Invoke btw, the following corrects it: Dispatcher.Invoke (new Action (() =>{}));

Comment: By the way, using Timers is kind of risky in this situation, because depending on the performance of the PC, the event may or may not actually still resize, in my case I had to use 300ms for it to more or less work, but it definitely pointed me to the correct direction, I'm going to change it to fit my necessity, eventually getting rid of timers. Thanks.

Comment: If you're also interested in knowing how it's performance-wise, this helped me reduce the overhead by 50%, now it's at 15% usage while resizing if a lot of Text is inside, IMO the RichTextBox is a huge mess in terms of performance, since it seems like that the Wrap Algorithm isn't the only factor causing these issues, anyways, once again thanks for pointing me to the right direction ;)

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. As for error - there is no error there, I always compile and run code before posting here. So maybe you use different version of WPF\.NET than I do, I remember indeed that Invoke or BeginInvoke required explicit Action.

Comment: As for the timers - I don't see how it can affect perfomance. Timer callback is always executed just once (see Timeout.Infinite), after X ms user stopped resizing, so timer itself cannot affect perfomance I'd say. Delay is of course configurable - if your users often resize slowly - better increase it.

Comment: It's not about the performance Timers consume, it's about how fast their computers are to execute the call correctly, using Timers and Delays in situations like these is all about timing, which will for example work perfectly in a PC with an i7 4790k clocked at 4Ghz while sometimes not working correctly on a slower Core2Duo or i3.

Comment: @StevenBorges The simplified `Dispatcher.Invoke` and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` overloads came about with .NET 4.5

Comment: Oh I see, I never worked with 4.5 before, I'm mainly doing 4.0, thanks for the info.